# cisco license install tftp no response from tftp server

Tags: cisco, tftp

I am trying to install a license through tftp in the CLI of a Cisco 2504 controller. My computer is a Mac Pro running Mojave version 10.14.6.

I have enable the tftp server on my mac. When I do `netstat -na |grep \*.69` I see the following:

```
udp4       0      0  *.69                   *.*                               
udp6       0      0  *.69                   *.*
```

My computer has the ip address 10.0.11.156 on the network. I have installed the license in the `/private/tftpboot` directory. I also did `chmod 766` on the `/private` directory `/private/tftpboot` and the license file itself.

I am able to get files by tftp from other machines on the network. On another computer on the network I entered:

```
tftp 10.0.11.156
tftp> get [license filename]
```

I got the response:

```
received 2236 bytes in 0.1 seconds
```

But when I go to the controllers CLI and enter

```
 (Cisco Controller)> license install tftp://10.0.11.156/[license filename]
```

the cli says `Transfering licenses from tftp://[license filename]`, then hangs for about a minute then responds

```
% Error: License file transfer failed - No reply from the TFTP server
```

In short, I'm able to tftp the file from another computer, but I get no response from the server when trying to install a license.

I forgot to add that I am able to ping from the controller to 10.0.11.156.

How do I install my license on my controller?

Answer (score 1):

No reply from the TFTP server means communication from the TFTP server back is not working.

- Make sure the correct port is open. If you say you can make transfers from another PC this may be fine, but check anyway.
- Make sure you do not have multiple WAN/network connections on the computer you use because routing may mess things up and your return packets may end nowhere because they try to return via another route/path. If you do, disable the unneeded one or use administrative distances to make the default route the correct one.

Comment: Thanks, this didn't fully solve the problem but it led me in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to hardwire a windows machine directly into the network instead of using the wifi, then used the tftpd64 app.